# Apache Spark SQL dataset groupBy with max function and different values in one more column

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset that is transformed by the following operations:

```
dataset.groupBy("userID", "itemID", "relevance")
    .agg(functions.max("value").as("value"));
```

in result I get dataset like this:

```
+------+------+-----+-------------------+
|userID|itemID|value|          relevance|
+------+------+-----+-------------------+
|     3|     1|  5.0| 0.2132007163556104|
|     3|     1|  5.0| 0.2132007163556104|
|     3|     2|  5.0| 0.1111111111111111|
|     3|     2|  5.0| 0.2222222222222222|
|     3|     3|  5.0| 0.3434343434343434|
|     3|     3|  1.0| 0.3434343434343434|
|     3|     4|  1.0| 0.5555555555555555|
|     3|     4|  5.0| 0.4999999999999994|
```

but I need to improve my query to remove duplicates, considering that MAX "relevance" must be selected. But in case when "relevance" is equal, MAX "value" must be selected.
Finally i should get dataset like this:

```
+------+------+-----+-------------------+
|userID|itemID|value|          relevance|
+------+------+-----+-------------------+
|     3|     1|  5.0| 0.2132007163556104|
|     3|     2|  5.0| 0.2222222222222222|
|     3|     3|  5.0| 0.3434343434343434|
|     3|     4|  1.0| 0.5555555555555555|
```

Sorry for a stupid and boring question, but could somebody help me to solve this task?

Comment: Use .distinct()

Answer (score 0):

I have converted dataset to JavaPairRDD < Tuple2 < Integer, Integer >, Tuple2 < Double, Double > > and then I have used method reduceByKey( x-> ... ), where in ... have described all logic. Not pretty, but it works.